# Requested Windows Runtime type 'Microsoft.Graphics.Canvas.CanvasDevice' is not registered on a Winforms Desktop Application

Tags: c#, winforms, win2d

I am trying to use Win2D in a desktop application. Project is building but i get a runtime error "Requested Windows Runtime type 'Microsoft.Graphics.Canvas.CanvasDevice' is not registered"

I know that in order to include Win2D i need to add the reference to the application's manifest file, which i have done.

The code:

```
private void CaptureMSFSScreen()
        {
            process = Process.GetProcesses().Where(p => p.ProcessName == "xxxxxxxx").Single();
            hwnd = process.MainWindowHandle;
            canvasDevice = new CanvasDevice();
            GraphicsCaptureItem item = CaptureHelper.CreateItemForWindow(hwnd);
            framePool = Direct3D11CaptureFramePool.Create(canvasDevice, DirectXPixelFormat.B8G8R8A8UIntNormalized, 1, item.Size);
            session = framePool.CreateCaptureSession(item);

            framePool.FrameArrived += (s, a) =>
            {

                using (var frame = framePool.TryGetNextFrame())
                {
                    ProcessFrame(frame);
                }
            };
            item.Closed += (s, a) =>
            {
                StopCapture();
            };

        }
```

The manifest file has this section inside:

```
  <file name="Microsoft.Graphics.Canvas.dll">
    <activatableClass
      name="Microsoft.Graphics.Canvas.CanvasDevice"
      threadingModel="both"
      xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:winrt.v1"/>

    <activatableClass      name="Microsoft.Graphics.Canvas.UI.Composition.CanvasComposition"
       threadingModel="both"
       xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:winrt.v1"/>

    <activatableClass
      name="Microsoft.Graphics.Canvas.Effects.SaturationEffect"
      threadingModel="both"
      xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:winrt.v1"/>

    <activatableClass
       name="Microsoft.Graphics.Canvas.Effects.BlendEffect"
        threadingModel="both"
        xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:winrt.v1"/>

    <activatableClass
      name="Microsoft.Graphics.Canvas.Effects.GaussianBlurEffect"
      threadingModel="both"
      xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:winrt.v1"/>

    <activatableClass
      name="Microsoft.Graphics.Canvas.Effects.ColorSourceEffect"
      threadingModel="both"
      xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:winrt.v1"/>

    <activatableClass
      name="Microsoft.Graphics.Canvas.Effects.CompositeEffect"
      threadingModel="both"
      xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:winrt.v1"/>

    <activatableClass
      name="Microsoft.Graphics.Canvas.Effects.OpacityEffect"
      threadingModel="both"
      xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:winrt.v1"/>

    <activatableClass
      name="Microsoft.Graphics.Canvas.CanvasBitmap"
      threadingModel="both"
      xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:winrt.v1"/>
    <activatableClass
      name="Microsoft.Graphics.Canvas.Effects.BorderEffect"
      threadingModel="both"
      xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:winrt.v1"/>
  </file>
```

Comment: Why did you tag this WinForms?

Comment: Because this is a winforms desktop applications that aspires to use WinRT component like Win2D. Shouldn;t i tag it?